# ClearSelection, AddToSelection only works for Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, selection

I’m trying to apply `.ClearSelection` and `.AddToSelection` methods in the Outlook VBA code snippet below (full macro in link) under three scenarios:

1. Select “Inbox” in the Outlook folder pane before executing the macro (ie, the “Preset” folder is Inbox);
2. Select “Junk Files” as the preset folder; and
3. Select “Deleted Items” as the preset folder.

Using “Inbox” as the preset folder works.

Using “Junk Files” or “Deleted Items”, the mailbox item is reported as

> not selectable in view.

However, for the failing folders, if I set a breakpoint at:

```
boolItemInView = ActiveExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(objInboxItem)
```

and then step through the remaining code, everything works!  (`boolItemInView` is True).

What needs to be done to get all three scenario’s to work? (Note: I'm using Outlook 365.)

Code Snippet:

```vb
' If Inbox item is selectable in current view then apply Selection methods

Set objInboxItem = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.GetLast

boolItemInView = ActiveExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(objInboxItem)

If boolItemInView Then

    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection

    ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection objInboxItem

End If
```

Complete macro code:
[Macro Code](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtFvLhSCoVhmgZoH1mPUkgciDysUsQ?e=dcqyPD)

Debugger results under three scenarios:

Pre-select the Inbox folder:
[Pre-select Inbox](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtFvLhSCoVhmgZoKzYxqJJhs_YAe4A?e=cAdNGw)

Pre-select the Deleted Items folder:
[Pre-select Deleted Items](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtFvLhSCoVhmgZoIdzZGwK2JdRrhrA?e=Ojfttf)

Pre-select "Deleted Items". Set debugger breakpoint at `boolItemInView = ActiveExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(objInboxItem)`:
[Set Breakpoint](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtFvLhSCoVhmgZoJh53g9u_yqP8mFQ?e=RbeZ9B)

Comment: What do you expect to get on the UI and what do you get for other folders now?

Answer (score 0):

When switch folders in Outlook by using the following code:

```
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objInbox
```

The view may not be ready for the [Explorer.IsItemSelectableInView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.isitemselectableinview) method calls. You may try to add any delay to let the explorer object render the new folder items. For example, you may try to handle the [Explorer.FolderSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.folderswitch) event which is fired when the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Pay attention to the fact that the `IsItemSelectableInView` method returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the item is selectable in the view. It does not indicate whether the item is visible in the view. If the item is contained within a collapsed group in the view, the method returns `false`. Double check whether it is your case or not.

Also the `IsItemSelectableInView` method raises an error if the current view is a conversation view.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried adding a delay ( sleep 10000 ) in front of the method .IsItemSelectableInView.  Same results.  So I tried a For Loop for 100 iterations around Sleep 100.  Same results.  I understand how to handle the Explorer.FolderSwitch event but all I can think to do there is insert a sleep delay.

Comment: Does the `IsItemSelectableInView` method return the same result in the `FolderSwitch` event handler?

Comment: Re: 2nd point.  I'm using the Compact view and have no collapsed groups.  In my testing I select an eMail maybe 6-8 items down from the top ( eMails are sorted in reverse chronological order based on time sent ).  The "last" eMail which is retrieved by the .GetLast method is usually at the top.

Comment: Re: .IsItemSelectableInView Idea.  I added code to switch the CurrentFolder twice:  First to "Deleted Items" and then back to "Inbox" under the scenario where the pre-set folder I select is "Inbox".  The code all works.  ( boolItemInView is true.  And the .ClearSelection and .AddToSelection methods work ).

Comment: Re:  IsItemSelectableInVIew method in the FolderSwitch event handler.  I'll run that next.  I haven't used event handlers in VBA before so will need to do a bit of research.

Comment: I can't get the FolderSwitch handler to fire.  Here are class module definitions:

Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 

Private Sub Class_Initialize() 

End Sub 

Private Sub myOlExp_Activate() 

End Sub 

Private Sub myOlExp_FolderSwitch() 

    Select Case myOlExp.CurrentFolder.name 
        Case "Inbox" 
            MsgBox ("Inside Inbox Event Handler") 
        Case Else 
    End Select 
    
    MsgBox ("Inside Folder Switch Event Handler") 
    
End Sub 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 

    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 

End Sub

Comment: Within my StudyPresetFolders sub I call the Initialize_handler subroutine as follows: 
Dim myOlExp as New MyOlExpClass
myOlExp.Initialize_handler

Comment: Sounds like a subject for another question/post here.

Comment: Progress Update:  The FolderSwitch handler now fires !  I moved the initialize_handler code to the Application_Startup event handler and placed it in ThisOutlookSession.  So now the FolderSwitch handler fires . . . but only when a folder is explicitly selected in the Outlook Folder Pane.   It doesn't fire under code :  Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = or Set myOlExp.CurrentFolder = .  On to more testing.

Comment: Progress Update:  The FolderSwitch handler is now working 100% as expected.  I removed the myOlExp class and code from my test subroutine.

Comment: Progress Update:  I added my code to test for IsItemSelectableInView to the FolderSwitch handler.  I get the same results as in my test code:  1) IsItemSelectableInView is True when the preset folder is "Inbox".  2) IsItemSelectableInView is False when the preset folder is "Junk Email" or "Deleted Items"

Comment: Unless someone has some really good ideas I'm going to set this problem aside for a while.  It's not essential for what I need to do ( for now ).